# Problems refreshing a Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I am having a problem using a Silverlight data grid with an observeable collection. I have crated a Silverlight data grid, filled an observerable collection from WCF RIA services and bound a collection to the grid.  It works fine for the first time, but when I change the  item source contents, the data is not refreshed in the grid.  When I double-click on the datagrid cells, the contents are displayed.  I may be missing some basic property settings. Can any one help?

Sample Code :

```
 App.BPIContext.Load(App.BPIContext.GetWellFieldListValuesQuery()).Completed += DataSource_WellFieldDataListValueLoadComplete;


ObservableCollection<ScheduleWellCustomFields> _userWellCustomFields = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleWellCustomFields>();

    void DataSource_WellCustomFieldsLoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _userWellCustomFields.Clear();
        App.BPIContext.ScheduleWellCustomFields.ToList().ForEach(c => _userWellCustomFields.Add(c));
        this.dtGridDrillingEngineer.ItemsSource = _userWellCustomFields;
    }
```

Comment: did you changed just the content of the ObservableCollection (i.e. Add, Remove) or did you set the ItemsSource property on the datagrid?
maybe you´d expect changes of your data. make sure you throw PropertyChanged for this cases.

Comment: I agree with Joachim Kerschbaumer, have set NotifyPropertyChanged in properties of ScheduleWellCustomFields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `this.dtGridDrillingEngineer.ItemsSource = null;` before `his.dtGridDrillingEngineer.ItemsSource = _userWellCustomFields;`

Comment: My problem is that the control doesn't repaint when it is initially used.

Answer (score 0):

Get the binding object and force a refresh:

```
        var bindingSource = TheDataGrid.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty);
        bindingSource.UpdateSource();
```

Comment: @Jordan that was not the question